# Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of Cohen-Macaulay modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

> Let $S=K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and $M$ be a Cohen-Macaulay $S$-module. This equality holds
>   $$ \operatorname{reg}(M)=\dim(M)+\max\{i\in\mathbb{Z}\colon P_{M}(i)\neq H(M,i)\}. $$

It's been proved in Eisenbud, "The Geometry of Syzygies" in Theorem 4.15. I can't understand it because that book has a lot of geometry in its proofs. Can you help me understand it? Or can anybody help me find a more algebraic version in other books?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use Bruns and Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, Theorem 4.4.3(b) noticing that the only non-zero local cohomology module occurs for $d=\dim M$.

---

Maybe a simpler approach (at least without local cohomology).
One knows that $\max\{i\in\mathbb{Z}\colon P_{M}(i)\neq H(M,i)\}=\deg H_M(t)$ (see Bruns and Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, Exercise 4.4.10). We can assume that $K$ is infinite and then there is a maximal $M$-sequence $x_1,\dots,x_d$ consisting of homogeneous elements of degree one. From Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra*, Proposition 20.20 we have $\operatorname{reg}M=\operatorname{reg}M/\underline{x}M$. On the other side, $H_{M/\underline{x}M}(t)=(1-t)^dH_M(t)$, so $\deg H_{M/\underline{x}M}(t)=d+\deg H_M(t)$. Since $\dim M/\underline{x}M=0$ we have $\operatorname{reg}M/\underline{x}M=\max\{i:(M/\underline{x}M)_i\ne 0\}=\max\{i:H(M/\underline{x}M,i)\ne0\}=\deg H_{M/\underline{x}M}(t)$, and we are done.

Comment: $H_M(t)$ is the Hilbert series, so what does $deg H_M(t)$ mean?

Comment: @Manos Beside of being a formal power series, $H_M(t)$ is a rational fraction and its degree (called the $a$-*invariant* of $M$) is the difference between the degrees of the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. I suppose this is the same $a$-invariant that is defined in 3.6.13 in B&H?

Comment: @Manos The two definitions agree for graded Cohen-Macaulay $k$-algebras. Instead, not all graded $k$-algebras have a canonical graded module although their Hilbert series is rational, so the above definition can be considered in some sense more general. On the other side, people working on local cohomology defines the $a$-invariant via the (graded) local cohomology modules, without reference to the (existence of) graded canonical module. (For short, there is a little mess here.)